# Error while uploading instructions using PyFirmata package

Tags: python, arduino

So I am trying to learn the PyFirmata module of python that allows us to write codes in Python and upload it to an Arduino Board.

I am learning it from [this website](https://realpython.com/arduino-python/).

Code that causes the inbuilt LED to blink:

```
import pyfirmata
import time

board = pyfirmata.Arduino('/dev/ttyACM0') #This Line gives error

while True:
    board.digital[13].write(1)
    time.sleep(1)
    board.digital[13].write(0)
    time.sleep(1)
```

But, When I run it( in Sublime Text 3) , I get this error:

> ```
> raise SerialException("could not open port {!r}: {!r}".format(self.portstr, ctypes.WinError()))
> ```

```
  serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port '/dev/ttyACM0': FileNotFoundError(2, 'The 
  system cannot find the path specified.', None, 3)
  [Finished in 7.0s]
```

Can Anyone help me to fix this error?

Comment: The str on the previous line is **not a comment**, so its indentation closes the if. 
Change it to a comment with `#`, it'll fix it.

Comment: Well, the picture contains the (problematic) docstring, your code doesn't.

Comment: You can use a docstring, but it has to be properly indented (4 spaces to the right should be ok). In python, a docstring **is** a statement; so it is meaningful and part of your code. Although in your case, if you right-indent it, it'll seem that it is explaining the break. So maybe it'll be better to put it below the elif

Comment: **Moderator Note** - Please do not overwrite a particular question that you have asked with a completely different and unrelated question. [Ask a new question instead.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The port you are trying to access doesn't exist or your program doesn't have permission to access it.

First checkout whether the port exist or not. If you have Arduino software installed, you can check from it. In case it's missing, another port should appear, smth like `/dev/ttyACM*`, where `*` is any number. Choose it and try running.
In case it exists, but the program still doesn't work visit the official arduino [site](https://www.arduino.cc/en/guide/linux).

This problem is solved in two command. Open terminal and type:

---

`ls -l /dev/ttyACM*`

Then you'll get something like this:

---

`crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 188, 0 5 apr 23.01 ttyACM0`

Here what we need is `dialout`. After the above command, type the below command, and the restart your device.

---

`sudo usermod -a -G your_username`

This should work, but there are cases, when it doesn't. Then you need to add your port to root access:

---

=============================================================================
`cd ~/etc/udev/rules.d`

In this directory, create a new `.rules` file and add the following to it:

---

`KERNEL=="ttyACM0", MODE="0666"`

This should work.

---